# How to ensure the correctness of AtomicLong addAndGet result

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomic-long

I want calculate current percentage in my muli-thread download programme.But there is a strange problem .
The  lastDownloadSize during the second download must be the sum of write and lastDownloadSize of lastDown.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bROGn.jpg)

There is my code

```
private long getDownloadSize() {
    synchronized (this) {
        final AtomicLong totalWriteCount = new AtomicLong(0);
        final AtomicLong lastDownloadSize = new AtomicLong(0);
        for (DownloadTask task : downloadTasks) {
            final long writeCount = task.getWriteCount();
            totalWriteCount.addAndGet(writeCount);
            final long downloadSize = task.getPosition().getDownloadSize();
            lastDownloadSize.addAndGet(downloadSize);
        }
        System.out.println("=====  writeCount : " + totalWriteCount + "lastDownloadSize : " + lastDownloadSize);
        return totalWriteCount.addAndGet(lastDownloadSize.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: you must define the `AtomicLong` as a *member* of your `class`. Defining it in the method has zero to none usage

Comment: What is the strange problem?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bROGn.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `totalWriteCount` and `lastDownloadSize` variables are local variables of the `getDownloadSize()` method. In that case, it does not make sense to use `AtomicLong`, because only a single thread can access them.

What you probably meant, is to make `totalWriteCount` and `lastDownloadSize` members of your class:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...
    final AtomicLong totalWriteCount = new AtomicLong(0);
    final AtomicLong lastDownloadSize = new AtomicLong(0);
    // ...

    private long getDownloadSize() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (DownloadTask task : downloadTasks) {
                final long writeCount = task.getWriteCount();
                totalWriteCount.addAndGet(writeCount);
                final long downloadSize = task.getPosition().getDownloadSize();
                lastDownloadSize.addAndGet(downloadSize);
            }
            System.out.println("=====  writeCount : " + totalWriteCount + "lastDownloadSize : " + lastDownloadSize);
            return totalWriteCount.addAndGet(lastDownloadSize.get());
        }
    }
}
```

However, also in that case, if they are only accessed from within `synchronized(this)` blocks, you do not need to use `AtomicLong`s, because the synchronized block already makes sure that they are only accessed by a single thread at the same time.

Comment: Aahh, you were quicker :)

Comment: Thank you every much .I understand

Answer (score 1):

Your current setup doesn't work, because you're using the `AtomicLong` the wrong way. Defining any `Atomic`-class in a single thread is just misusage of that API.

Now why have I said single thread, well you're synchronizing when someone enters your method, which just says that only one thread at a time may use said method. Which leads us to the problem:

- The `AtomicLong` is a local variable

You probably wanted to define your `downloadSize` and `totalWriteCount` as a *member* of your `class`. E.g:

```
public class YourClass {
    private final AtomicLong totalWriteCount = new AtomicLong(0);        
    private final AtomicLong downloadSize = new AtomicLong(0);

    /* constructors and other methods */

    private synchronized long getDownloadSize() {
        for (DownloadTask task : downloadTasks) {
            final long writeCount = task.getWriteCount();
            totalWriteCount.addAndGet(writeCount);
            final long downloadSize = task.getPosition().getDownloadSize();
            lastDownloadSize.addAndGet(downloadSize);
        }
        System.out.println("=====  writeCount : " + totalWriteCount + "lastDownloadSize : " + lastDownloadSize);
        return totalWriteCount.addAndGet(lastDownloadSize.get());
    }
}
```